# Retrieving text from HTML sibling elements using QueryPath in PHP

Tags: php, html, querypath

I'm extracting data from some old HTML files using PHP and the QueryPath library. Extraction is easy when the element I need has a unique css3 ID or class, but this isn't always the case. I have some files containing the following type of data:

```
<div id="dataDiv">
<div class="1">Heading1</div><div class="2" title="">Data1</div>
<div class="1">Heading2</div><div class="2" title="">Data2</div>
</div>
```

I would like to use QueryPath to search for a DIV of class "1" containing a certain string of text ("Heading2", for example), and then retrieve any text in the sibling div of class 2 directly next to it. (It would retrieve "Data2" in this case).

Is there built in functionality in QueryPath that allows me to navigate to an element based on the text it contains? If so, once I locate that element, how can I then get the content text of its next sibling element?

Comment: Just to let you know, html classes may not start with a number.  Also I would advise attempting to set this up in another way.

Answer (score 1):

My natural idea is to is the `not()` function. An example :

```
$qp2 = qp($tb)->find('table tr')->not('table tr table tr');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the sibling operator in CSS 3:

```
qp($html, 'div.1:contains("Heading1") + div.2')->text();
```

The above gets `<div class="1">` whose heading is `Heading1`, then gets the adjacent sibling whose class is `2`.